# UICollectionView Layout with Section Header for SearchBar and another dynamic Section Header for the Title

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to create 2 header for the collection view.

First header is the `UISearchController` and the section header is used for Category that I get from JSON

Here's the JSON Example

```
"tag": "req_kingdom_classification",
"success": "1",
"error": "0",
"data": [
    {
        "Category": "Animalia",
        "SubCategory": "Mamals",
        "imagePath": "Mamals.jpg",
        "keyword": "",
        "activity": "AA"
    },
    {
        "Category": "Animalia",
        "SubCategory": "Reptile",
        "imagePath": "Reptile.jpg",
        "keyword": "",
        "activity": "AA"
    },{
        "Category": "Plantae",
        "SubCategory": "Embryophyta",
        "imagePath": "Embryophyta.jpg",
        "keyword": "",
        "activity": "PP"
    },
    {
        "Category": "Bacteria",
        "SubCategory": "Streptomyces",
        "imagePath": "Streptomyces.jpg",
        "keyword": "",
        "activity": "BB"
    }, ...
]
```

The image is already inside the device because i've called an API to fetch the image.

And here's what i want to create

```
------------------------------------------------------------- 
|                          SearchBar                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                          Category1                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|     Category1.imagePath1    |     Category1.imagePath2    |
|    Category1.SubCategory1   |    Category1.SubCategory2   |
|                                                           |
|     Category1.imagePath3    |     Category1.imagePath4    |
|    Category1.SubCategory3   |    Category1.SubCategory4   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                          Category2                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|     Category2.imagePath1    |     Category2.imagePath2    |
|    Category2.SubCategory1   |    Category2.SubCategory2   |
|                                                           |
|     Category2.imagePath3    |     Category2.imagePath4    |
|    Category2.SubCategory3   |    Category2.SubCategory4   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

I use `UISearchBar` for searching each `SubCategory`

How to make custom `UICollectionView` like this using Swift?

Comment: Show us some code you've tried and what the exact problem is please.

Comment: Use `collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:`.  If indexpath.section == 0 then return view with search bar and title label else view with title label

Comment: @Teetz I've problem at adding searching into the section header sir.
Here's the code https://github.com/renzrz/gitCoe

Comment: @RajeshKumarRIs there any example to try it sir?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WE have not header and footer part in collection view in iOS.
but you can manage tableview in collection cell because in table view have header and footer view.

and your problem is solve with this ans I hope so.

Comment: You can use `collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:` method to create header and footer for collectionview

Comment: @Ravi Vaishnav I've try using collection cell inside table view, but it only scroll horizontally... How to make it looks like collection cell sir?

Comment: @Renzrz sir according to your design you need to put collection view in table cell then you got look like as design which you given in question on above.
means one table cell in collection view and another table cell in another collection view you can manage from this.